# Why does my Perl CGI program return a server error?

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi, cgi-bin

I recently got into learning cgi and I set up an Ubuntu server in vbox. The first program I wrote was in Python using vim through ssh. Then I installed Eclipse on my Windows 7 station and created the exact same Perl file; just a simple hello world deal.

I tried running it, and I was getting a 500 on it, while the Python code in the same dir (/usr/lib/cgi-bin) was showing up fine. Frustrated, I checked and triple-checked the permissions and that it began with #!/usr/bin/perl. I also checked whether or not AddHandler was set to .pl. Everything was set fine, and on a whim I decided to write the same exact code within the server using vim like I did with the Python file.

Lo and behold, it worked. I compared them, thinking I'd gone mad, and they are exactly the same. So, what's the deal? Why is a file made in Windows 7 on Eclipse different than a file made in Ubuntu server with vim? Do they have different binary headers or something? This can really affect my development environment.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Testing.";
```

Apache error log:

```
[Tue Aug 07 12:32:02 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.8] (2)No such file or directory:     exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.pl' failed
[Tue Aug 07 12:32:02 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.8] Premature end of script headers: test.pl
[Tue Aug 07 12:32:02 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.8] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

This is the continuing error I get.

Comment: What do the apache logs show?

Comment: The first rule of debugging CGI is that if you get a 500,  you look in the server logs. The second rule is that if something is going wrong, you run it from the command line on the same machine to see what it outputs.

Comment: I would stake money on this being a \r\n on the #! line instead of a \n

Comment: Also, the Content-Type: header should have \r\n\r\n at the end.

Comment: @ikegami - didn't the OP imply that the server was running Ubuntu?

Comment: @Flexo, oh, yes, I misunderstood. He did his editing on Windows, but both environment are unix environments. Your hypothesis is very likely correct. Make it an answer! Deleting my earlier comments.

Comment: @tripleee, apache handles `LF` just fine; it sends `CR LF` to the client. [ This is a repost of an earlier comment with the irrelevant parts removed ]

Comment: I updated the original post with the Apache log. The file very much exists and has appropriate permissions. The only difference between that file and the one that works properly is on what OS and environment they were made.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have some spurious `\r` characters on the first line of your Perl script when you write it in Windows.

For example I created the following file on Windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

code goes here
```

When viewed with hexdump it shows:

```
00000000  23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62  69 6e 2f 70 65 72 6c 0d  |#!/usr/bin/perl.|
00000010  0a 0d 0a 63 6f 64 65 20  67 6f 65 73 20 68 65 72  |...code goes her|
00000020  65 0d 0a                                          |e..|
00000023
```

Notice the `0d` - `\r` that I've marked out in that. If I try and run this using `./test.pl` I get:

```
zsh: ./test.pl: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/perl^M: no such file or directory
```

Whereas if I write the same code in Vim on a UNIX machine I get:

```
00000000  23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62  69 6e 2f 70 65 72 6c 0a  |#!/usr/bin/perl.|
00000010  0a 63 6f 64 65 20 67 6f  65 73 20 68 65 72 65 0a  |.code goes here.|
00000020
```

You can fix this in one of several ways:

1. You can probably make your editor save "UNIX line endings" or similar.
2. You can run `dos2unix` or similar on the file after saving it
3. You can use sed: `sed -e 's/\r//g'` or similar.

Your apache logs should be able to confirm this (If they don't crank up the logging a bit on your development server).

Comment: This is it. Thanks for running those tests for me. I really appreciate your time and response.

Comment: Thanks, very well explained.. It took me hours to reach here and find your solution!!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it can.

- One environment might have a module installed that the other might not.
- Perl might be installed in different locations in the two environment.
- The environments might have different versions of Perl.
- The environments might have different operating systems.
- The permissions might be setup incorrectly in one of the environments.
- etc

But instead of speculating wildly like this, why don't you check the error log for what error you actually got?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are just text files. Of course, it's possible to write unportable programs, trivially by using `system()` or other similar services which depend on the environment.