# Apache2 Returns 404 on Perl Script

Tags: perl, apache2, http-status-code-404

[SOLVED]

After managing to get the server to throw 500's I then had to relocate the line;
to a different location within the .pl script.

;-)

I have located this article VIA SO: [Why does my Perl CGI program return a server error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850192/why-does-my-perl-cgi-program-return-a-server-error)

This is the same issue I am presently experiencing with Ubuntu 12.04.02 running A2, yet making the settings changes within /etc/apache2/sites-available which appear correct are making no positive influence.

=> Within the perl script (just beneath the call to perl interpreter) script I am having issue running from the browser which *is* functional VIA CLI;

```
 print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
 print STDERR "OK so far\n";
 print "Succeeded.";
```

=> This server is very basic at this point in configuration, and is only intended to host 1 web-site. At this point no domain has been assigned and I am just accessing it VIA LAN IP 10.0.0.50, which should not be an issue, I think?

=> My doc root is `/var/www`
=> The cg-bin is located: `/var/www/cgi-bin`

=> Presently /etc/apache2/sites-available/default is utilizing the following parameters with respect to ScriptAlias;

```
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

=> I have set the above to the following but still the server returns 404;

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

=> /var/log/apache2/error.log provides the following:

```
[Thu Apr 18 23:06:22 2013] [error] [client 10.0.0.10] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/acctmanager.pl
[Thu Apr 18 23:07:45 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 18 23:07:46 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

=> The top of** /etc/apache2/sites-available/default **appears as;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory
```

If anyone has some idea of my error(s) I would be greatly appreciative for your time and input.

Thank you

Best Regards

Comment: I have now made changes in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default which now makes the server return 500's.                                                                 /var/log/apache2/error.log: [Fri Apr 19 10:56:32 2013] [error] [client 10.0.0.10] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/acctmanager.pl' failed
[Fri Apr 19 10:56:32 2013] [error] [client 10.0.0.10] Premature end of script headers: acctmanager.pl

Comment: At Stack Overflow, you don't add SOLVED to the title of your question.  Instead, you select the checkmark below the score of the answer that you feel best solved your problem.

Comment: I am sorry for my error in placing SOLVED within the TITLE

Comment: BTW: I received no replies, I fixed the issue myself. So your REQUIREMENT to : Instead, you select the checkmark below the score of the answer that you feel best solved your problem

Comment: Then you should write up your solution as an answer and mark that as accepted, so the next person with your problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have u+x permission on the script/dir folders and the script resides in the ScriptAlias Directory, Check this link again to see if you have missed any config.  -

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

Comment: You are correct, I did find the problem to be related to file permissions,thank you..