# APACHE 2 error: cgi file in /cgi-bin/ shows "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Tags: apache, webserver, apache2, beagleboneblack

I am using apache 2 on the beaglebone black flashed with a Debian 10 image to run a server using a simple cgi file.

The https://hostname.com works fine. But when i get into the usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.cgi (URL becomes https://hostname/cgi-bin/test.cgi)  territory, I get the 404 error. I have seen questions with similar issues but none of that trouble shooting works.
test.cgi looks like this :

test.cgi:

```
#!/bin/bash
 echo "Content-type: text/html"
 echo '<html><head>'
 echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">'
 echo '<title>Hello BeagleBone</title></head>'
 echo '<body><h1>Hello BeagleBone</h1><para>'
 hostname
 echo ' has been up '
 uptime
 echo '</para></html>'
```

The relevant conf files :

apache2.conf:

```
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
#added code for cgi directory
#ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "usr/lib/cgi-bin/"

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

serve-cgi-bin.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Heres what my error log looks like :

```
[Sat Nov 19 23:08:38.140834 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2313:tid 3069685168] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Sat Nov 19 23:08:38.255524 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2313:tid 3069685168] AH00489: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 19 23:08:38.255708 2022] [core:notice] [pid 2313:tid 3069685168] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

File Permissions are on.
I am using derek molloy's exploring beaglebone as a reference.

This code is supposed to create an apache server displaying the HTML contents. Instead, I get the 404 :

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at 192.168.2.3 Port 80

apachectl -M output:

```
 
    - Loaded Modules:  core_module (static)  so_module (static)  watchdog_module (static)  http_module (static)  log_config_module (static)  logio_module (static)  version_module (static)  unixd_module (static)  access_compat_module (shared)  alias_module (shared)  auth_basic_module (shared)  authn_core_module (shared)  authn_file_module (shared)  authz_core_module (shared)  authz_host_module (shared)  authz_user_module (shared)  autoindex_module (shared)  deflate_module (shared)  dir_module (shared)  env_module (shared)  filter_module (shared)  mime_module (shared)  mpm_event_module (shared)  negotiation_module (shared)  reqtimeout_module (shared)  rewrite_module (shared)  setenvif_module (shared)  status_module (shared)
```

Comment: Your CGI config will only be loaded if `mod_alias` and either `mod_cgi` or `mod_cgid` are enabled.  Have you checked that they are?  [`apachectl -M` will list all enabled modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794566/how-to-check-mod-headers-and-mod-expires-modules-enabled-in-apache).  Also, what are the permissions on both `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` and `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.cgi`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109941/apache2-returns-404-on-perl-script

Comment: Hey @Don'tPanic , fitting name. Right now, both are set to -rwxrwxr-x perms. Furthermore, when  I use apachectl -M , those mods dont show up, I've updated the post at the end with what does show up

Comment: You were right- cgi mod was not enabled and now is. It works! Thanks Don't Panic, I felt more support from you than my professor :)